# How to copy Google Translate's Chinese transliteration using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to extract Google Translate's pinyin transliteration of a Chinese word using Selenium but am having some trouble finding its WebElement.

For example, the word I look up is "事". My code would be as follows:

```
String word = "事";
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/zh-CN/" + word);
```

When I go to the actual page using my browser, I can see that its pinyin is "Shì" and that its id, according to Inspect Element is `src-translit`. However, when I go to view source, though the `id="src-translit"` is present, you don't see anything resembling "Shì" nearby. It's simply empty.

Thinking that the page has had no time to load properly. I implemented a waiting period of 30 seconds (kind of a long wait, I know, but I just wanted to know if it would work).

```
int timeoutInSeconds = 30;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("src-translit")));
```

Unfortunately, even with the wait time, transliteration and its text still returns as empty.

```
WebElement transliteration = driver.findElement(By.id("src-translit"));
String pinyin = transliteration.getText();
```

My question, then, is: what's happened to the `src-translit`? Why won't it display in the html code and how can I go about finding it and copying it from Google Translate?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly waiting (eg: `Thread.sleep`)? For example, you know that the text should appear within a few seconds of typing in the input. Rather than having selenium figure out when it should check the element. The condition of visibility should satisfy that, but maybe it doesn't. Have you printed out what the current HTML is before you try to get the element? To verify that your input has been typed in correctly.

Comment: Yes, `driver.getCurrentUrl()` returns the correct web address. Unfortunately, `Thread.sleep` makes no difference.

Comment: Not URL, the page source.

Comment: `driver.getPageSource()` returns the same html I'm able to view with the browser (i.e., the element with id `src-translit` is still there, but there's no content).

Comment: Like I mentioned, on the Inspect Element side, everything's proper. The source code is missing what's present on the user side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like javascript isn't being executed. Looking at the [docs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/HtmlUnitDriver), you can enable javascript like this

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

or

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
```

See if that makes a difference.

EDIT:

I still think the problem is related to javascript. When I run it using `FirefoxDriver`, it works fine: the AJAX request is made, and `src-translit` element has been updated with `Shi`.

Workaround:

In any case, monitoring the network traffic, you can see that when you want to translate 事 , it makes an AJAX call to

```
http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&sl=zh-CN&tl=zh-CN&hl=en&sc=2&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&pc=1&oc=1&otf=1&rom=1&srcrom=1&ssel=0&tsel=0&q=%E6%B2%92%E4%BA%8B
```

Which returns JSON:

```
[[["事","事","Shì","Shì"]],,"zh-CN",,[["事",,false,false,0,0,0,0]],,,,[],10]
```

Maybe you could parse that instead for now.

Comment: Sorry. Even with that change, the WebElement's text still comes up as empty. :(

Comment: @user2323030 Updated with workaround. I don't know how to get it to work using the web element approach with HtmlUnitDriver.

Comment: Fantastic! That workaround looks like it's exactly what I need. Unfortunately, I don't know any of the steps you took to get that answer. Could you give me some instructions, or point me to a page that gives this kind of instructions? Thank you!

Comment: @user2323030 Most modern browsers have support for monitoring network traffic. I'm using google chrome so I just ctrl+shift+J to open the inspect, then click on the Network tab, and then when I type in some input in the box, you will see the webpage sending a request to the server. Click on that request to see where it's going, and then you can just do the same on your end.